# http:// for urls in spider code, not in url list txt file

Tags: scrapy

I have very large url lists without http://. It's a lot of work to prefix all urls in these files. They are too large for my computer and I have to split them before and then edit. This all together takes a very long time.

Is there a way to prefix the urls in spider code, not in url list?

Comment: `start_requests`

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain a little more?
What exactly and where should I place it? I use start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()] to call the url lists.

Comment: you can use start_requests to invoke scrapy requests from a generator. So you could lazy load all the URLs by creating a generator that modifies each URL at a time and then scrapy will make the request.https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/spiders.html#Spider.start_requests

Comment: The method is also featured in the Scrapy tutorial: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html